# Changing front pad and rotors, no problem currently with caliper, should I change the caliper any way on 171k miles car?

Tags: toyota, camry, brake-calipers

Camry LE 2005, 171k miles. Got examined the brakes professionally by mechanic. He says only pad and rotor needs replacement.  A non-professional-but-car-knowing friend is advising to get replaced the caliper as well (because  of age of car he suggests I will need it soon). Should I get caliper replaced? Curent calipers are original  that came with car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the litmus I'd use to figure this out:

1. Are there any problems with the current calipers?
2. Are the calipers leaking?
3. Do the calipers retract after braking (if they don't retract the brakes will drag)?

If the answers to these three simple questions are "No", then don't change them. Calipers will continue to work as long as they work. They are one of those parts which really do not have an expiration date ... well ... until they expire. IMHO, don't change them until you need to change them.